# Problema ao passar informação no meu login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

estou recebendo essa exception no momento de realizar meu login

> ```
>  ERROR [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (default task-10) An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: No value present
>     at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:127)
>     at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
>     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
>     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
>     at java.util.Optional.get(Unknown Source)
>     at br.com.netservicos.sic.service.authenticatioin.UserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailService.java:73)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:115)
> ```

O metodo que está sendo usado para realizar o login:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws      UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(login)) {

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Não foi possível localizar o Usuário");
        }

        Optional<Usuario> optional = usuarioService.findByLogin(login);

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {

            LOGGER.error("Não foi possível localizar o login: {}", login);

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Não foi possível localizar o Usuário.");
        }

        Usuario usuario = optional.get();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = usuarioService.carregarPerfil(usuario.getPerfil());

        Principal principal = new Principal(usuario.getId(), usuario.getNome(), usuario.getSobrenome(), usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getEmail(),
                usuario.getPerfil().getNome(), usuario.getSenha(), usuario.getSituacao(), authorities);

        LocalDate data = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime entrada = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime saidaAlmoco = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime voltaAlmoco = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime saida = LocalTime.now();

        Folha novaFolha = new Folha();
        Optional<Folha> findDateUser = folhaService.findByDateAndUser(novaFolha.getData(), novaFolha.getIdUser());

        if ( if (findDateUser.get().getData()))) {

            novaFolha.setData(data);
            novaFolha.setUsuario(usuario);
            folhaDAO.persistir(novaFolha);

        } else if(novaFolha.getEntrada() == null){

            novaFolha.setEntrada(entrada);
            folhaDAO.update(novaFolha);
        } else if (novaFolha.getEntrada() != null){

            novaFolha.setSaidaAlmoco(saidaAlmoco);
            folhaDAO.update(novaFolha);
        }



        return principal;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece no trecho destacado em amarelo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a descrição abaixo da documentação da API, caso ele não encontre valor, ele sobe esta exception que você esta recebendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--